# RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition(lastItem) scrolls to bottom where last item is partially visible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, linearlayoutmanager

Im working on chat type screen where new text msg item is added in list and recyclerView is scrolled to last position of the list but the last item is partially visible, and does not scroll till end of bottom when the keyboard is open. I have added

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
```

to the recycler view. 
I have also tried to use recyclerView.layoutMangaer.smoothScrollToPosition, ScrollBy() method, and also used some 300 msec delay to scroll.
Nothing worked.

Will appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: you added this line anywhere in your code? `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Comment: Can you some code for more understanding.

Comment: yes, Please check i have given some recyclerView code